# kafka getting failed authentication with ssl handshake error

Tags: docker, ssl, apache-kafka

I am trying to enable ssl authentication for kafka but it is failing with ssl handshake error but it is working with plaintext.

docker-compose file

```
`version: "3"
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: zookeeper
    restart: always
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    environment :
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka
    volumes:
      - /Users/Documents/kafkaSample/tmp:/etc/kafka/secrets
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
      - 9093:9093
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      ZOOKEEPER_SASL_ENABLED: 'false'
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092,SSL://0.0.0.0:9093
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,SSL://localhost:9093
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL
      KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_FILENAME: kafka.keystore.jks
      KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_CREDENTIALS: ssl.creds
      KAFKA_SSL_KEY_CREDENTIALS: ssl.creds
      KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_FILENAME: kafka.truststore.jks
      KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_CREDENTIALS: ssl.creds
      KAFKA_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH: 'required'
      KAFKA_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: SSL`
```

client-host-properties file

```
    
bootstrap.servers=kafka:9093
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.location=/etc/kafka/secrets/kafka.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=testtest
ssl.keystore.location=/etc/kafka/secrets/kafka.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=testtest
ssl.key.password=testtest
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
```

getting the error while connecting with producer using this command
`kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list kafka:9093 --topic test --producer.config /etc/kafka/secrets/client-ssl-host.properties`

```
[2023-05-12 13:34:42,735] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Bootstrap broker localhost:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2023-05-12 13:34:42,853] ERROR [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9093) failed authentication due to: SSL handshake failed (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2023-05-12 13:34:42,853] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Bootstrap broker localhost:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2023-05-12 13:34:43,025] ERROR [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9093) failed authentication due to: SSL handshake failed (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2023-05-12 13:34:43,026] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Bootstrap broker localhost:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2023-05-12 13:34:43,143] ERROR [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9093) failed authentication due to: SSL handshake failed (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2023-05-12 13:34:43,143] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Bootstrap broker localhost:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2023-05-12 13:34:43,268] ERROR [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9093) failed authentication due to: SSL handshake failed (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2023-05-12 13:34:43,269] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Bootstrap broker localhost:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

Comment: Where are you running that command from? Notice the error says `localhost:9093`, but you set `--broker-list kafka:9093`... Also, your environment variable values for the files should be absolute paths

Comment: Related https://github.com/bitnami/containers/issues/32285#issuecomment-1545552651

Comment: @OneCricketeer I am running it from inside docker. path mentioned is the path where properties reside in the container. I tried with 
`
docker exec -it kafka kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9093 --topic test --producer.config /etc/kafka/secrets/client-ssl-host.properties
`
but its also failed with 
`
 Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9093) failed authentication due to: SSL handshake failed 
 [Producer clientId=console-producer] Bootstrap broker localhost:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
`

Comment: You'll need to clarify how you've created your JKS files. Plus as mentioned, use absolute paths for each

Answer (score 0):

finally it got worked. if anyone still facing issue then they can refer

```
version: "3"
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: zookeeper
    restart: always
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    environment :
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka
    volumes:
      - /Users/Documents/kafkaSample/tmp:/certs
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    hostname: kafka
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: SSL://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: 'SSL://0.0.0.0:9092'
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION: '/certs/client.keystore.p12'
      KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD: 123456
      KAFKA_SSL_KEY_PASSWORD: 123456
      KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION: '/certs/client.truststore.jks'
      KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD: 123456
      KAFKA_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM: ''
      KAFKA_SECURITY_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL: 'SSL'
```

properties file

```
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.location=/certs/client.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=123456
ssl.keystore.location=/certs/client.keystore.p12
ssl.keystore.password=123456
ssl.key.password=123456
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
```